# How to design Desk calendar mockup?

Tags: mockup

I have searched many website for free Desk Calendar mock up's but there are no such things i am happy with. But now i want to create a mock up. So if you help me how i can make a photo realistic desk calendar mock up, this will be great.

Should i use 3D software ? Or just Photoshop & Illustrator ?

*** Yesterday I've made this photo using Cinema 4D. But i don't have the idea how can i match my graphics with those rings [up side of the image]]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you simply use Photoshop to superimpose your calendar design onto an existing photo. Creating a 3D mockup seems like overkill to me, especially if you're concerned with getting the spiral just right. There is plenty of royalty free (and even public domain) imagery out there. Finding a suitable template photo should be relatively easy, but it might take you a while to find the "perfect" image.

Answer (score -3):

Well bro if you are very new in design world you should use Google template for calendar but there are also few other techniques 
If you can use adobe illustrator and Photoshop u can simply download various free templates design or you can create complete custom file as well if you are a pro but there is no need to use 3d at all